# Acessing data buffer of typed memoryview in Cython

Tags: pointers, cython, memoryview

I have a function expecting array pointers in Cython, e.g. with the signature

```
cdef void foo(DTYPE_t* x)
```

and a function which receives a typed memoryview from which I would like to call the first function, e.g.:

```
def bar(DTYPE_t[:,::1] X not None):
    foo(X[0])
```

Which naturally does not even compile. I've been trying for some hours now to figure out a way to access the data pointer underlying the memory view i.e. something like `X.data`.

Is there a way to achieve this? I sadly can not adept `foo` to accept memoryviews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this:

```
foo(&X[0,0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is that simple, it's quite embarrassing

```
&X[i,j]
```

i.e. the call will become

```
foo(&X[i,0])
```

Which, by the way, also works with the old style numpy arrays, which are initialized like

```
object[int, ndim=2, mode='strided'] X
```

PS: If you would like to pass C-array, `X[i][j]` would be required, which equally works for typed memoryviews.

Comment: Use ```X[i,j]``` not ```X[i][j]```

Comment: You are of course right. I've opted for `X[i][j]` because this syntax would work equally for C arrays. I am going to edit my answer.